# How to get coordinates of a point after an image is rotated? (with images)

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, rotations

I have a problem that involves a rotating image and finding a previously known point.

Firstly, there is a sequence with the rotation.

[image]

1. We start with an empty image.
2. A line is drawn vertically, from (0, 0) to a point in the y-axis (assume 50, possible values range from 0 to 100 which is the max). We will call this point 'a'.
3. The image is rotated by 'x' degrees (known value).
4. Another line is drawn vertically, from (0, 0) to a point in the y-axis (assume 60). We will call this point 'b'.

---

*My question is,* **how do I get the coordinates of point 'a' relative to point (0, 0)?**

---

Thank you all so much and I really appreciate your replies, good or bad. Please do tell me if you need more info on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotating a point $(0,A_y)$ on a plane about the origin by $x$ degrees (counter-clockwise) is given by 
$$
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
A_x' \\
A_y' \\ 
\end{array}
\right] 
= 
\left[ 
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos x & -\sin x \\ 
 \sin x & \cos x \\  
\end{array}
\right] 
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
A_y \\ 
\end{array}
\right],  
$$
where $(A_x',A_y') = (-A_y \sin x, A_y \cos x)$ denotes your new position. Relative to point $B$, the coordinates are:
$$(-A_y \sin x, A_y \cos x - B_y)$$

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems that I made a mistake, I edited my post about a minute ago. The coordinates I am looking for is now relative to (0, 0). I apologize for the late edit.

Comment: So you can just ignore the last formula, because the coordinates relative to $(0,0)$ are shown a couple of lines earlier.